# Use preg_split to split a string on "," and " and "

Tags: php, regex, split

I now split the sting op , only like this:

```
$a_string = preg_split('/[,]/', $sting);
```

I also want to split the sting on " and " but i can't find the right regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_split('/(?:,| and )/', $sting);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also just do:

```
$arr = preg_split('/,| and /', $str);
```

as `|` (alteration) has a very low precedence and binds last.

Comment: true, I am a sucker for (?:) grouping though reads better and less error prone :)